# Mysql PHP insert with quotes and double quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into a table that contains both quotes and double quotes.  How can i escape them?

The value i want to add is:

```
 default=1,name='Bob',lastName="Jones"


 $ins = "INSERT into table (field1,field2,fiel3,) values ('data1','data2',????)";
```

If i use single quote, the Bob part gets broken. If I use double quote, the Jones part gets broken.

If i use mysql_escape_string what would this look like?

```
$data3 = mysql_escape_string(????);
```

Again if i use single quote, the Bob part gets broken. If I use double quote, the Jones part gets broken.

I know its a terrible db design but I have no control over the fields i need to add or the syntax of the values.  I have to insert the value exactly as seen above.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you'd want to do that.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Fred-ii- because the db I am adding data to was designed by clowns....any good db would seperate field 3 into individual fields, but not this db.....

Comment: Schema issues aside, getting data into it is just a matter of properly escaping things, and the best way to do that is with placeholder values.

Comment: Luckily, the world has moved on from this API

Comment: you could escape the double quotes then, it'd be one way, or use a prepared statement

Comment: yea, this db stuff is because this vendor's API is 1 step above useless. i have had to reverse engineer a lot to get to this point....

Comment: In PHP, to consider quotes/double quotes as a string value, use a backslash before the quotes/double quotes. For instance, `data1='John' data2='\"John\"'` will be stored as **John** and **"John"**. It is also recommended to define such values in variables and not directly into INSERT queries.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi That's not right either. Let the driver escape things however it determines it should. MySQL can run in different modes where double-quotes actually mean something different. Your driver will know what to do. Sorry to be so harsh but this is dangerously misundertstood by too many people.

Comment: @tadman can you give an example of a placeholder you are referring to?

Comment: It's in the links in my original comment. In practice it looks like `VALUES (?,?,?)` or `(:name, :age, :shoes)` where you bind those values after preparing your statement. This *always* works if your query is valid. You can put whatever you want in there, and so long as the column allows it, it will get inserted properly, without errors.

Comment: and if you have no control over the incoming data, you could also replace with quotes with single quotes or other, `str_replace()` or a preg function could also do the trick here.

Comment: so  `code $var = "Bob\"\\'s house"` and ` $stmt->bindValue(':name',$var)`

Comment: That's the idea for PDO which is certainly not a bad idea. Ali answered with a `mysqli` solution that's similar, and that's the way to do it as well. I'd steer towards PDO over `mysqli`, it's more generic, not MySQL only, and has better binding options. The named placeholders are a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Use prepared statements

Look at this.

First connect with improved `mysqli`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into table (field1,field2,fiel3,) values (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$data1,$data2,$data3);
$stmt->execute();
```

Where `$mysqli` is your connector.

In this way you have also prevented from SQL Injection.

Comment: Great example, exactly how it should be done with `mysqli`.

Comment: There, now he has the whole solution.

Comment: I know how to use prepared statments.  my question is.  what if sss is actually Bob's Wacky "House" of Cards

Comment: You either do this `'Bob's Wacky "House"'` or `"Bruce Wayne is 'Batman'"` it will work. Just try it and enjoy the power of mysqli

Comment: You forgot to put a database in the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 7, and from what I understand you can't escape quotes. At least not properly. I'd recommend you go to PDO, as it's compatible with different database types, and it's in my opinion easier to use than the `mysqli_*` functions. Although I'll let you know that `mysqli` is capable of escaping quotes.

Since there is already an answer with a mysqli example, here is a short example of using PDO to escape quotes:

```
$dns = "mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

$connection = new PDO($dns, $user, $password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
    ':username' => $username,
    ':password' => $password
]);
```

Now remember this only escapes quotes, it does not filter your inputs. So before you insert any foreign data(form data), use the `filter_var()` function based on what you want to filter, e.g: `$string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`. Or you could do:

```
 $statement->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO_PARAM_STRING);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a little function which mimics the original mysql_real_escape_string but which doesn't need an active mysql connection. Could be implemented as a static function in a database class. Hope it helps someone.

```
<?php 

function mysql_escape_mimic($inp) { 

    if(is_array($inp)) 
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp); 

    if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) { 
        return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp); 
    } 

    return $inp; 
} 
?>
```

Source: [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#101248)

Comment: Awesome. Earlier I use `str_replace("'","''");` and It also works.